# How do we know that all the equivalence classes are infinite and there are infinite equivalence classes?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm given this definition of an equivalence relation.

> Let $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ be formulas (with the same set of free variables) written in some fixed language $\ell$. We say that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent, and write
>   $\phi \equiv \psi$, if:
>
> For all sets M, with any interpretations of the symbols of $\ell$ in M and for any
>   tuple m from M, we have M$\models \phi(m)$ if and only if M$\models \psi(m)$.

I proved that this is an equivalence relation on the set of all formulas,
but now I don't know how to prove that all the equivalence classes are infinite and the fact that there are infinite equivalence classes.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To show that the classes are infinite, observe that for any sentence $\phi,$ $$\phi\equiv \phi\land\phi\equiv \phi\land\phi\land\phi\equiv\ldots.$$

To show that there are infinitely many equivalence classes assuming you're working in first order logic with equality, we can write the statement "$M$ has $2$ elements" as $$ \forall x\forall y(x\ne y\to \forall z(z=x\lor z=y))\land\exists x\exists y(x\ne y)$$ and we can similarly write the statement "$M$ has $n$ elements" for any $n\in\mathbb N.$ These statements are in different equivalence classes and there are an infinite number of them.

Comment: So for example you have a formula $(\forall x) x=x$. What will be it's equivalence class? Would it just be the same formula over and over again?

Comment: @PratyushChopra This formula is true in any structure. Its equivalence class will be the class of all formulas in your language that are true in any structure, i.e. all valid formulas.